# siteminder does not build headers

Tags: siteminder

We are running SiteMinder 6 - that's the reason why we cannot ask for SiteMinder support.
We have noticed a strange behavior making a user unnable using the application she had been authorised to.
We have checked the policied,the apache reverse proxy configuration, the web agebt configuration, and all sound ok.
But capturing data between the reverse proxy and the back end application, we noticed that the RP sends no header, although the logs says it does.
had anybody suffered from a similar issue?
We rebooted the RP, without success.

thank you for your help.

Comment: So your SM WA is running on the RP and not the backend server? This is only happening for 1 user account? If you run a "dump headers" page on the web server behind the RP you do not see any of the SM_ headers?